# How to delete the command message once the user sends it

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need the bot to delete the author's message once the command is sent

```
    @commands.command()
    async def dolor(self,ctx):
        await client.delete.message(ctx.message)
        await ctx.send(f"from {ctx.author.name}")
        await ctx.send("https://tenor.com/view/baby-sad-omg-desolated-devastated-gif-9710732")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `client.delete.message()`. To delete a message you need to use the [`delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) method in the `discord.Message` object.

`ctx.message` will give you the instance of the `discord.Message` object.

So, your command would look like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def dolor(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"from {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send("https://tenor.com/view/baby-sad-omg-desolated-devastated-gif-9710732")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```